# Conversion to polar equation

Tags: polar-coordinates

I would to know when asked to convert an equation to polar what it means.For example $ x^2+x+y^2-2y=0 $

My understanding so far tells me I need to derive an equation in form of:
$$ r^2=x^2+y^2$$

Meaning for this case:$ x^2+y^2=2y-x $

Hence $r^2=2y-x$

Please help.

Comment: Converting to polar co-ordinate doesn't mean of the form $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$. Rather it means from $(x,y)\to(r,\theta)$$$x=r.cos(\theta)\ \ \ \  y=r.sin(\theta)$$$$\therefore\ r^2=x^2+y^2$$

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+x+y^2−2y=0$

$r^2+r\cos(\theta)-2 r\sin(\theta)=0$

$r+\cos(\theta)-2\sin(\theta)=0$

This means that your graph can be expressed in terms of $\theta$ as:

$r(\theta)=-\cos(\theta)+2\sin(\theta)$.

You can check the shape of this graph using calculator.

Comment: ,sorry to come back late. I don't understand your second line of $r^2+r\cos(\theta)-2 r\sin(\theta)=0$ and how the values map to $x^2$ or $r^2$ or $y^2$